# How to detect if the MDC Snackbar has closed in JS?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, material-design, snackbar, mdc-components

I'm using Material Design's Snackbar and VueJS and I'd like to be able to detect when the snackbar has closed.

Snackbar has a built in property called isOpen, so I'm able to use  `return this.snackbar.isOpen;` as a boolean. However, there isn't a similar `isClosed` property, and when the snackbar does close, `isOpen` remains true.

It seems that `isOpen` is not reactive to closing, just to opening. But I want something to trigger when the snackbar is closes after having been open. Would appreciate any advice

I init my snackbar like so:

```
this.snackbar = new MDCSnackbar(document.querySelectorAll(".mdc-snackbar"));
```

Answer (score 3):

I solved it:

```
const snackbarElement = document.querySelector(".mdc-snackbar");
this.snackbar = new MDCSnackbar(snackbarElement);

snackbarElement.addEventListener("MDCSnackbar:closed", (event) => {
```

Previously, I was trying to add the eventListener to the snackbar itself

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to listen to the `MDCSnackbar:closed` event, documented in the [events section of the documentation](https://material.io/develop/web/components/snackbars/#events).

Since you tagged your question with `vue.js`, I assume you are integrating MDC into a Vue app. In which case I would suggest you have a look at [`vue-mdc-adapter`](https://github.com/stasson/vue-mdc-adapter). They have more Vue-specific [documentation for a snackbar](https://stasson.github.io/vue-mdc-adapter/#/component/snackbar) as well. Your snackbar might then be something like:

```
<mdc-snackbar v-model="snack" @hide="handleHide"></mdc-snackbar>
```

> `@hide` – notify listeners that the snackbar has been hidden.

Comment: I saw that but didn't find the docs clear enough to tell me the correct way to do this. I stuck a listening on and passed a debugger into the callback and it never triggered

Comment: `this.snackbar.addEventListener('MDCSnackbar:closed', () => { debugger } )`  is the code I used unsuccessfully

Comment: Also tried `    window.addEventListener('MDCSnackbar:closed', () => {debugger;})`

Comment: And I init my snackbar using: `this.snackbar = new MDCSnackbar(document.querySelectorAll(".mdc-snackbar"));`

Comment: do you know how I add an event listener to it? The docs aren't clear here

Comment: Thanks Aurel, the team are trying to avoid using dependencies where possible so I'll see if I can pick through the source code and extract the bits I need.